# Adobe Reader (or any third part software) on Steam Play

Tags: wine, steam, adobe-reader

A week or so ago, Valve released a feature that implements compatibility to Windows games on Steam via Proton. As far as I understood, the engine is basically Wine. I was wondering whether it would be possible to install other software via the same engine, cheating on Steam so that he thinks he's installing a game from its database. I am interested in using Adobe Reader, and I have tried to install it directly through Wine or PlayonLinux, but it does not run well, and eventually crashes. Sorry for the possible misconceptions in the text, I am not a Linux expert so be kind:)

Comment: If it doesn't work well in wine, I don't see why it should work better in Proton, it being "basically Wine".

Comment: Steam Play's "Proton" is just a per-installation version of Wine - if the app didn't work on Wine to begin with, it will probably still not work any better.  And unless Steam Play lets you install these 'third party software' via their system you're unlikely get to install things.

Comment: What kind of answer is that? It being basically "wine" does not mean Adobe is gonna work equally on both.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, [you can use Proton much like Wine itself](https://redd.it/99fjzw). It seems like DXVK for DirectX 11 & 12 apps and controller support is the biggest reason to do so, although better multi-threading would also help some apps. IDK much about Proton though, and maybe there is more it's bringing to the table.

[Wine's AppDB](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=847) implies that the most recent version of Wine can basically run Adobe Acrobat DC Pro (Silver rating) so it should do "okay" with the Standard edition too.

You may be better off looking for [an alternative](https://alternativeto.net/software/adobe-acrobat/) that's compatible with your OS though as they would be more likely to be stable and work as advertised. Many Linux apps listed there have been discontinued, but since you're willing to try Wine anyways something for Windows could (theoretically) run better through Wine than Adobe's Acrobat. Of course it's unlikely almost any of them will offer all the equivalent features, so if there's some specific things you want from Reader then running it may be the only way to get them.